# Karate: call feature without modifying headers

Tags: karate

I have a feature A and an auxiliary feature B:

Feature A:

```
#stuff

* call read('B.feature')

#stuff
```

With those steps the headers (and cookies) in feature B are inherited from feature A and I want them to be completely independent (as it feature B was a real test feature like A).

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#shared-scope

```
* def result = call read('B.feature')
```

Comment: I would expect a flag in the call method or a different method, but it worked, thanks!

Comment: you probably should use REST-assured, it is a better fit for you, it all normal Java, no weirdness, very comfortable, everything will work as you "expect"

Comment: No, I like the karate REAL DSL